# tabulation of two string variables using Stata

Tags: stata

The data I have are (just an example):

```
choice1      choice2
--------------------
apple        mango
banana       apple
mango        apple
mango        banana       
apple        banana
```

What Stata command can I use to have the following result, in which tabulation of `choice1` and `choice2` is combined?

```
choice   number
---------------
apple      4
banana     3
mango      3
```

`choice1` and `choice2` are two separate string variables.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) See also the help center on how to post a good question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard problem much discussed on Statalist (www.statalist.org). One solution is to use the user-written program `tabm` from the `tab_chi` package on SSC, which you should install with

```
ssc inst tab_chi
```

Your example is easily tabulated using that. An alternative is to restructure the data, at least temporarily:

```
. clear 

. input str6 choice1 str6 choice2

       choice1    choice2
1. "apple"        "mango"
2. "banana"       "apple"  
3. "mango"        "apple"
4. "mango"        "banana"       
5. "apple"        "banana"
6. end 

. tabm choice1 choice2, transpose 

            |       variable
     values |   choice1    choice2 |     Total
 -----------+----------------------+----------
      apple |         2          2 |         4 
     banana |         1          2 |         3 
      mango |         2          1 |         3 
 -----------+----------------------+----------
      Total |         5          5 |        10 


. d

Contains data
 obs:             5                          
vars:             2                          
size:            80 (99.9% of memory free)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
choice1         str6   %9s                    
choice2         str6   %9s                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  
Note:  dataset has changed since last saved

. preserve 

. stack choice1 choice2, into(choice) clear 

. tab choice 

      choice |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
 ------------+-----------------------------------
       apple |          4       40.00       40.00
      banana |          3       30.00       70.00
       mango |          3       30.00      100.00
 ------------+-----------------------------------
       Total |         10      100.00

 . restore 

 . d 

 Contains data
  obs:             5                          
 vars:             2                          
 size:            80 (99.9% of memory free)
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
               storage  display     value
 variable name   type   format      label      variable label
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 choice1         str6   %9s                    
 choice2         str6   %9s                    
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sorted by:  
 Note:  dataset has changed since last saved
```

Searching the database for threads mentioning `tabm` is one way to see more. `search multiple responses` in Stata to learn about other solutions and discussions.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks so much for the help. the tabm function does not work in the stata 10 that i am using. But the 2nd answer (stack and tab) works for me just fine. Really grateful for your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `tabm` is a command, not a function. As it happens, I developed the example above in Stata 10, so your problem is not that, but some other mistake you made: perhaps you missed the point that **you must install it first**. `tabm` was written for Stata 8.2 and works in that and any higher version. (I'm the author.) If you found the answer helpful, you can accept it, and gain reputation thereby.

Comment: Hi Nick, i am using stata 11. I tried the help and search command to find it tabm command working but says unrecognized command. Also tried . ssc inst tab_chi
host not found
http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/ either
  1)  is not a valid URL, or
  2)  could not be contacted, or
  3)  is not a Stata download site (has no stata.toc file).

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using Stata 10 or 11, my comments still apply. I just typed `ssc desc tab_chi` and can see a package description, so the site is accessible at present. See also `help netio` about your network set-up.

Comment: Hi Nick, turns out i had to change the proxy setting using help netio. I downloaded the tab_chi. tabm is really cool and really helps me a lot. Thanks gazillion.